# Sort by option not available in Quote Line Item related list

Tags: administration, page-layout, related-list, configuration

On the 'Quote' page related list, I am trying to add the **Sort By:** column option for the 'Quote Line Item' related list. But I am not able to see this option.
[image]

I tried for the other related list on Quote, and this option is available.
[image]

How can I enable it for 'Quote Line Item' related list columns?

Answer (score 1):

This is working as designed. I checked internally with our Salesforce team and found that in the backend code, isSortCustomizable() property is set to false implying end users will not be able to use the "sort by" in RelatedQuoteLineItemList.

I am currently unaware of what technical or product reasons have driven this change but will let you know as I hear back from the team.

You might want to log this as an Idea on [Salesforce IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/search#t=All&sort=relevancy) platform to have this functionality implemented.